# Application menu with root owned windows?

Tags: unity, root, appmenu

How do I let root-owned windows use global menu?  I already have the 'Title Bar Info' Compiz plug-in telling me that the window is root's, I don't want the existence of the menu bar telling me that it's not my window as well.  I would like some consistency.

Answer (score 2):

I reported this [issue](http://pad.lv/592842) almost a year ago. It's a design/engineering problem that hasn't been solved yet, partly because of the security issues involved.